# Python type annotations: Proper way to annotate functions returning library object

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, python-typing

What is the proper way to annotate a type function returns in this code?

```py
from requests import Request, Session

def make_request(method: str, url: str) -> ??? : # Response object will be returned
    request = Request(method, url).prepare()
    session = Session()
    r = session.send(request)
    return r
```

Should be `Response` imported for that, or `TypeVar` should be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should import `Response` and use it.  Creating `TypeVar` complicates typing for no good reason:

1. If your module had already had `Response` used somewhere (and thus imported), you wouldn't even think about not using it for the type hint.
2. If you introduce another function or whatever to this module later and you need `Response` class there, you'll be stuck with `TypeVar` not matching actual `Response`s
3. If your module is imported by another module (or even third-party one), a function returning `Response` disguised as a custom `TypeVar` would make code more confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?

```
from requests import Request, Session, Response


def make_request(method: str, url: str) -> Response : # Response object will be returned
    request = Request(method, url).prepare()
    session = Session()
    r = session.send(request)
    return r
```